# How to interpret an estimation system that predicts individual measurement poorly but provides unbiased mean?

Tags: regression, estimation, sampling, bias

I am trying to develop an automatic system to use machine to measure or estimate the length of a certain species. The system output gives quite strange result (figure below): From a regression point of view, the system measurements $x_i$ does not predict the true value $y_i$ (linear regression R^2=0.03, or Spearman correlation =0.19). However, the mean of the machine estimates is not significantly different than the mean the of true measurements (not significant from paired t-test, or equivalent test). So how can i intepret the regression and t-test result: $y_i-x_i$ has a small(or large) spread around zero , but $y_i-\hat{\beta_0} -\hat{\beta_1}x_i$ (residual from regression) has a large spread around zero? Can someone give more insight on this statement?

If my goal is to estimate the mean of the species length, does it mean that the system gives good enough performance?

Thanks

[image]

Comment: There are no true values below zero, but there *are* several estimated values below zero. I would caution against any model that predicts negative length.

Comment: sorry @James, I forgot to mention that the plots are log-transformed. Could you ignore the actual meaning of the values.